# glueing problem when deploying my flask application locally

Tags: python, flask

I will summarize a bit what happens, I have my very simple flask application but I have noticed some problems, currently I use flask to make REST requests to azure but sometimes when making requests the requests are queued and the only way to follow their course is to go to the console where the local server is running, press Enter or down arrow key to remove the queue, I am afraid that if this happens locally it will probably happen at some point when the application is deployed in production and there I will have no way to be pressing Enter or down arrow.

This is an example of 1 of the many functions I query, the logic is not very complex but still sometimes it glues.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, Response, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from dotenv import load_dotenv, dotenv_values
import subprocess, json
from waitress import serve
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
load_dotenv()
URL_CORS = os.getenv("URL_CROSS_ORIGIN")
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins':URL_CORS}})
RSCGROUPDESA = os.getenv("RESOURCE_GROUP") 
GTWNAMEDESA = os.getenv("GATEWAY_NAME")


@app.route('/api')
def get_data():
    data = {'message': 'Hello, Docker!'}
    return data

@app.route('/listRules', methods=['GET'])
def listRulesAppGateway():

    cmdListRules = f"az network application-gateway rule list --gateway-name {GTWNAMEDESA} --resource-group {RSCGROUPDESA}"

    output = subprocess.run(cmdListRules, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
    ruleName = json.loads(output.stdout)

    nameList = [{'name': r['name']} for r in ruleName if len(r) > 0]

    return jsonify({'name_list': nameList})

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

I would be grateful if you could help me with recommendations or if there is any way for the server to avoid as much as possible these queues of requests and not generate a response.

Comment: maybe try adding the `--yes`  parameter

Comment: where do I add that "--yes"?

Comment: I would try `f"az network application-gateway rule list --gateway-name {GTWNAMEDESA} --resource-group {RSCGROUPDESA} --yes"` Though that is just a short in the dark on my part